# Changing Axis of a Listplot based on values in a list

Tags: plotting

I have a table with some data that I plot against each other, say like this.

```
test = Table[i + j, {i, 7}, {j, 5}];
ListContourPlot[test]
axesrange={0,1.5,5,6,9,10,17};
```

This will give me a contourplot with x-axis ranging from 0-5 and y-axis from 0-7. However, I want the y-axis to change based on the axisrange list I have. I know I can plot those values on the axis, but I actually want the plot to scale based on the values, as the interval between the values is different for each set of values.
Any ideas how to do this?

[image: example]

Comment: Not entirely clear what you want, but would `PlotRange` be useful to you?

Comment: Perhaps you could draw a picture of the desired output in this case

Comment: I posted a picture showing what I want (I hope). Basically I want to scale the y-axis according to the values in my axesrange, so 1 corresponds to 0, 2 corresponds to 1.5 and so on.

Comment: It's still not clear what you are looking for here. If you need to scale something usually you would divide by a constant. If you need to change the plot range you need to use, ListContourPlot[test,PlotRange->{{},{}}]. Showing the output from Mathematica and explaining what its not doing and what you want fixed would make it easier to answer.

Comment: `DataRange` may be it.

Comment: @matti0006, is the following interpretation close to what you mean: you want to _rescale_ the y-coordinates of **each contour line individually**, y-coordinates of the first contour line rescaled to `{0,1.5}`,  y-coordinates the second to `{0,5}`, ... and  the last one to  `{0,17}`. If so (_and_ you don't mind removing the contour shadings) I think it can be done by post-processing the output of your `ListContourPlot`. If this is somewhat accurate description of what you need, please edit your question (cut and paste from this comment if you need) and I will vote to reopen the question.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
test = Flatten[Table[{j, i, i + j}, {i, 7}, {j, 5}], 1]
axesrange = {0, 1.5, 5, 6, 9, 10, 17};
f = Interpolation[Transpose@List[Union[test[[All, 2]]], axesrange]];
GraphicsRow[{ListContourPlot[test], ListContourPlot[test /. {x_, y_, z_} :> {x, f@y, z}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks a bundle, this looks pretty much like what I want!